# How would I use Double End Of Line resistors on stuff like relay, transistor, Piezo, Output devices so I could detect if the line was cut or shorted?

Tags: alarm

I'm trying to understand how you would go about detecting if the line was cut or shorted on an output to a device like a transistor, relay, piezo, etc, or other input devices like a Hall effect sensor. I have some ADS1115 that detect magnetic contacts which seems to work fine with the 2x 4.7kohm DEOL resistors with the green checkmark.

Here you can see this working with the 4 states 1.1V (ON) & 1.65V (OFF) with the contact switch state. 0V (Short Test), 3.3V (Cut Test) works in a Falstad simulation:

https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l5YCsA2ATI8NV1QdlwMyQAcqyAnObiIpDTXYgKYC0YYAUAE4gEHLhkdPKkF06AFlxxuICXDG9+iumHizU8pQL47lk6ZA1bdITZIUGZANzNb2okeDCjxcugWgEoPmIg4A7ma4og7BoUJQgdp2HspgkUZB5uGxMUkxKaZOGaZ5yvLiHADOaYUx5W4AZgCGADbFTNEpYSnERUHl7WndRgAO7qqRXR6+0fl6AjklaSlzIb4gtQ1NyfYus1pGAB5mSGYEEmbIUwTUR2BHAMIArgAuADrFACpMxXccu+jEZuQeqBBUORvBcjgBlAAWAHsuI8Xm8Prt5ORBKIJMRqAkMKCQABBAB29ShAHMngBJfF9e6fOzUAgY3hA3h-OTgI4AEShMKeVyh+LuNQAxh9SvNRNkFqolvVGjSyBACIhzhIMPxJGyQJybgAjOpMJ4AUXxABMngB5KpPAAyAEt8frigAlN4294w4ocIA

I then have another 16-bit MCP23017 GPIO expander outputting to devices. Then the ADC attached to the output as well to detect the DEOL resistors marked with red arrows.

I really have no clue what I'm doing. Which I'm sure shows please help :D

Thank you!

[image: Diagram of component layout]

[image: DEOL Resistor for reed switch contact]

Double End Of Line Resistor schematic

Processor reading the analog values on the line to determine the state:

```
Normal state, sensor not triggered
0: 8424 (1) 
-----------------------------------------------------------
Sensor triggered.
1: 15689 (2) 
-----------------------------------------------------------
Wire shorted. Possible tampering.
2: -1 (0) 
-----------------------------------------------------------
Open circuit. Cut or tamper triggered.
3: 26452 (3)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a really complicated task, and I think you'll struggle to find one type of short/open detector that can cope with a wide range of devices. For example, even if you monitor the current & voltage for each of the lines (which involves a lot of ADC channels), your piezo buzzer consumes very little current, so is almost indistinguishable from an open circuit.

The approach I'd adopt is to have a row of output drivers, that take their supply from a single source, and then put an ADC on that source to measure the overall voltage & current. Then every time you switch a device on, check the step-change in supply current. If there is an open-circuit, that step will be zero; if short-circuit, that step will be high, so there needs to be some current-limiting in the supply (or the drivers) to avoid damage.

In order to detect the low-current devices such as transistors or piezo buzzers, you have to add a load resistor across them, increasing their current so it can be detected.

This approach won't be perfect, but I think it'd be a realistic way to get close to your objectives, without a lot of complication.